# How to partition while reinstalling ubuntu via LiveUSB without losing data?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, live-usb, gparted

I don't come from a computer science background, so I have a lot of basics missing in my knowledge, so please bear with me.

In short:
I have persisting problem with my main ubuntu on my machine as it keeps failing to boot by any way possible via grub. Now, I decided to fix it with LiveUSB ubuntu to backup missing data and "reinstall" ubuntu.

The current problem:
run `ubuntu 16.04.3 installer` -> choose language -> in install type window: I either `erase everything and install ubuntu` OR `something else`.

**NOTE:** At this point, the installer doesn't detect any operating system in the computer. Plus, my SSD drive is encrypted.

I don't want to erase everything, I want to keep my data and in the same time to reinstall the os as the only solution I have left to solve the booting problem.

Now, I don't know how to deal with the following existing partitioning and what should I do with it to just reinstall the system:
[partition tablesin the ubuntu installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXiNM.png)

As you see:
 - My data is in the first partition plan and I can change the use of the partitions, but am not able to resize them or whatever.
 - the second partition table is still raw and untouched (I actually clicked on `new partition table..` and removed the previous one I found as I landed in the window. It looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QIhZ.png)

And, this is what displayed I open **gparted**:
[gparted partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cWxA.png)

If there is any needed information from command line or whatever, I would be more than happy to share. I am just not sure, what else could be needed here.

Shortly, all what I need to know is how to deal with this partition tables to reinstall ubuntu without losing my data.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your partitions. You do NOT seem to have a separate data partition, so reinstalling your (encrypted) system partition will definitely delete all your data permanently and unrecoverably. Instead of asking about reinstall, why don't you ask about merely fixing GRUB so it properly locates your system partition?

Comment: GRUB is in the boot partition sda1, right? So, reinstallation is not an option here. ... Well, I am not sure what is the problem and lost a lot of time because of it and therefore thought to install the whole OS again.